# How to add 'logout' function to a Admin site in Django

Tags: python, django

In my Django project, I created a separate admin.py and in that file, I extend the AdminSite class as follows:

```
class UserAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = "Admin Site"
    site_title = "Manage User and Groups"
    login_form = AuthenticationForm

def has_permission(self, request):
    return request.user.is_active and request.user.is_admin_user
```

But then I discovered that in that admin site, there is no link on the top left to the logout. How do I add that to the admin site?

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending AdminSite you should already have a logout function,

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L349:

```
@never_cache
def logout(self, request, extra_context=None):
    """
    Logs out the user for the given HttpRequest.
    This should *not* assume the user is already logged in.
    """
    from django.contrib.auth.views import logout
    defaults = {
        'current_app': self.name,
        'extra_context': dict(self.each_context(request), **(extra_context or {})),
    }
    if self.logout_template is not None:
        defaults['template_name'] = self.logout_template
    return logout(request, **defaults)
```

if you look at the admin site's base.html it's looking for url with the namespace admin:logout

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html#L46:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:logout' %}">{% trans 'Log out' %}</a>
```

Are you overwriting the default admin urls.py? You can check the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names) for details on setting namespace.

Comment: I have not overwritten the default admin urls.py. And when I access the logout page of the admin site manually by typing in the address, it works fine. It's just that there is no "logout" button on the top left corner of the admin site.